# Android: How to listen to new Gmail messages

Tags: android, gmail-api

I'm creating an app that will use email message body to send SMS to a number. Anytime new mails are sent, the app gets the message and sends to a number.

Gmail api provides a way to fetch inbox messages passing the message id as a parameter

But is there a way to listen to a new mail? So that my function runs anytime a new mail is received.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/

Comment: Try this documentation: [Getting Gmail mailbox updates](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push). This will notify your app (it will be the trigger) then you'll send SMS to the number.